# Inexplicably slow query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this result-set:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.cust_name, SUM(l.line_subtotal) FROM customer c
    -> JOIN slip s ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
    -> JOIN line l ON l.slip_id = s.slip_id
    -> JOIN vendor v ON v.vend_id = l.vend_id WHERE v.vend_name = 'blahblah'
    -> GROUP BY c.cust_name
    -> HAVING SUM(l.line_subtotal) > 49999 
    -> ORDER BY c.cust_name;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key           | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_vend_name           | idx_vend_name | 12      | const                |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ref    | idx_vend_id                     | idx_vend_id   | 4       | csv_import.v.vend_id |  446 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_cust_id,idx_slip_id | PRIMARY       | 4       | csv_import.l.slip_id |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,cIndex                  | PRIMARY       | 4       | csv_import.s.cust_id |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I'm a bit baffled as to why the query referenced by this `EXPLAIN` statement is still taking about a minute to execute. Isn't it true that this query only has to search through 449 rows? Anyone have any idea as to what could be slowing it down so much?

Comment: where are you getting a minute from? `4 rows in set (0.04 sec)`

Comment: That is the duration of the explain statement, not the actual query

Comment: I am no expert, but you may find increased performance if you split the query into two.  Create a temp table with the grouping, add an index on the sum column on that temp table and query that temp table for records > 49999

Comment: Could the temp table be created on a rather slow media? I'd be curious to see the result of [Show Profile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: @scrowler The first time the execution plan is built, and then re-used (in the same connection). Now, everytime such a query is called from a web application, the execution plan is not cached, that is why in some situations it takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `having sum()` is the root of all evil. This forces to mysql to make two joins (from `customer` to `slip` and then to `line`) to get the value of the `sum`. After this it has to retrieve all the data to properly filter by the `sum()` value to get a meaningful result.

It might be optimized to the following and probably get better response times:

```
select  c.cust_name, 
        grouping.line_subtotal
  from customer c join 
  (select c.cust_id, 
          l.vend_id,
          sum(l.line_subtotal) as line_subtotal 
     from slip s join line l on s.slip_id = l.slip_id
   group by c.cust_id, l.vend_id) grouping 
      on c.cust_id = grouping.cust_id
   join vendor v on v.vend_id = grouping.vend_id 
 where v.vend_name = 'blablah'
   and grouping.line_subtotal > 499999
 group by c.cust_name
 order by c.cust_name;
```

In other words, create a sub-select that does all the necessary grouping before making the real query.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your select vendor query first, and then join the results with the rest:

```
SELECT c.cust_name, SUM(l.line_subtotal) FROM customer c
    -> JOIN slip s ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
    -> JOIN line l ON l.slip_id = s.slip_id
    -> JOIN (SELECT * FROM vendor WHERE vend_name='blahblah') v ON v.vend_id = l.vend_id 
    -> GROUP BY c.cust_name
    -> HAVING SUM(l.line_subtotal) > 49999 
    -> ORDER BY c.cust_name;
```

Also, do vend_name and/or cust_name have an index? That might be an issue here.